# Octopus deployment caching

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy, octopus

We are using octopus to deploy our project. A bunch of steps which gets executed during the deployment. One of them is a powershell script and that powershell script is a work in progress.

However to test the script we have to perform a dummy check in or can create a new release in octopus after we change the build powershell script step, and it will pick up the build steps straight away and does not cache, else the script which gets executed is the previous version.

I do not know if this is caching or some other issue. I think this is some kind of issue with octopus or setting which I am missing.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important aspect of deployment automation is ensuring that deployments are repeated exactly each time they run.

When you create a release in Octopus Deploy, the artefacts, process, and variables are all "locked in" for that release. This means no matter what changes you make, for the lifetime of that release it will be performed identically every time.

If your deployment tool didn't do this, the same relase could work in your test environment, but then fail in the live environment because the deployment process changed in some way.

In effect, you release changes to the deployment process in the same way you release changes to the application itself.

This is why you need to create a new release in Octopus Deploy in order to see the changes you make.

Answer (score 2):

This is both a blessing and a curse... On the one hand - your existing release scheduled for `Production` is protected from changes being made in lower environments. On the other hand - you are forced to recreate a `release` if you need to make a slight process change mid-cycle. This is arguable the correct approach since you would want to test any changes - but maybe not relevant if your changes can only be tested in higher environments (e.g maybe only `Production` is load balanced).

The software does allow to update `Variables` mid-cycle, but not `Process Steps`. I believe this feature is been requested for a future release.

http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/5130-how-to-update-a-single-variable-in-an-existing-release